# VBA Macro for Internet Explorer - code run well on debugging 1 by 1 command but didn't work if i run the whole program

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I'm new with VBA Macro using for automate the internet explorer.

I've used it for creating bot to follow other online shopping follower (e-commerce).
Actually the code run well if I use debug 1 by 1 command, and it worked (can do the follow thing).
But if I run the whole program, the code just operate maybe several command & stopped (but it didn't error).

I used it for e-commerce (sho.ee).
The step is:

- open IE for other shop's followers
- grab all the link
- open the new link in new IE
- follow them, close the new IE
  and looping.

If I run step by step it worked.
Hope you guys could help me which wrong with the code.

Here's the code => i changed the name of the shop by xxx

```
Sub Followers()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim ieAnchors As Object
    Dim Anchor As Object


    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate "https://shopee.co.id/shop/xxx/followers/"

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set ieAnchors = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("shop-href")

   For Each Anchor In ieAnchors

        result = Anchor

        If result <> result_prev Then

           Dim objIE_1 As InternetExplorer
           Dim ieBtn As Object
           Dim Btn As Object

           Set objIE_1 = New InternetExplorer
           objIE_1.Visible = True
           objIE_1.Navigate Anchor

           Do While objIE_1.Busy = True Or objIE_1.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

           Set ieBtn = objIE_1.Document.getElementsByClassName("shopee-button-outline shopee-button-outline--complement shopee-button-outline--fill ")

                      For Each Btn In ieBtn
                      Btn.Click
                      Next Btn

           objIE_1.Quit

        result_prev = Anchor

        End If

   Next Anchor

End Sub
```

Comment: If it runs OK while stepping through but not if run without stepping, that typically suggests you have a timimg problem: some process on the page is not complete before the next line of code runs.  Try adding some Wait lines where you think the problem might be.  Check the return values from your `getElementsByClassName` to make sure you're getting the objects you expect.

Comment: Hallo @TimWilliams . Yup that's just work. thanks alot

Comment: @inuyasha, you can try to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes pages load in parts, registering as complete before all elements have loaded. In these cases I use application.Wait to force the program to wait a set amount of time for page loads:

```
'wait five seconds
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

If it is a simple page, I will have a Do loop a check for ReadyState to avoid slowing the program down unnecessarily:

```
'wait for page to load
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE or ie.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it worked. by adding Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Sub Followers()

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ieAnchors As Object
Dim Anchor As Object


Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate "https://shopee.co.id/shop/xxx/followers/"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set ieAnchors = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("shop-href")

For Each Anchor In ieAnchors

```
    result = Anchor

    If result <> result_prev Then

       Dim objIE_1 As InternetExplorer
       Dim ieBtn As Object
       Dim Btn As Object

       Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) 
       Set objIE_1 = New InternetExplorer
       objIE_1.Visible = True
       objIE_1.Navigate Anchor

       Do While objIE_1.Busy = True Or objIE_1.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

       Set ieBtn = objIE_1.Document.getElementsByClassName("shopee-button-outline shopee-button-outline--complement shopee-button-outline--fill ")

                  For Each Btn In ieBtn
                  Btn.Click
                  Next Btn

       objIE_1.Quit

    result_prev = Anchor

    End If
```

Next Anchor

End Sub